# Unable to create IoT-HUB using Arm template with skuName value "F1" in azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an IoTHub using ARM Template on powershell, but I'm getting the error message": "Max number of Iot Hubs exceeded for sku = Free, Max Allowed = 1, Current = 2 ".

JSON for Parameters for the IoTHub in the ARM Template has been listed below :-

"skuName": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "F1",
 "metadata": {
"description": "Specifies the IotHub SKU."
 } },

"capacityUnits": {
"type": "int",
"minValue": 1,
"defaultValue": 1,
"metadata": {
"description": "Specifies the number of provisioned IoT Hub units. Restricted to 1 unit for the F1 SKU. Can be set up to maximum number allowed for subscription."
}}

Apart from these parameters, I also listed out location and IoTHubName as parameters and their corresponding values in another parameter.json file ,both of which I call in the powershell command while deploying the ARM Template.

I expect the ARM Template to be deployed,but I got the following error :-

ERROR: Resource Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs 'meddev-aihtwo'
failed with message '{
  "code": 400019,
  "httpStatusCode": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Max number of Iot Hubs exceeded for sku = Free, Max Allowed = 1, Current = 2 in the
subscription Id: xxxxxxxxxx. If you contact a support representative
please include this correlation identifier: xxxxxxxxxx, timestamp:
2019-09-08 15:39:

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, you have reached the limit of Azure subscription. According to my research, you only can create one free SKU Azure IOT Hub in one Azure subscription. For more details, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#iot-hub-limits
[image]

Besides, if you want to create more free SKU Azure IOT Hub, you need to raise a support ticket on Azure Portal to Azure support team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request.